# How can be get CDATA data by xslt?

Tags: oracle, xslt

I am able to parse xml to json by 
http://www.armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/12-oracle-xml-and-json-goodies

But when any CDATA  come it fail . Can you tell me the rule of xslt so that i can copy all data that is written in CDATA as it is in json .

```
> select
> packagename.itstar_xml_util.xml2json(xmltype('<ArticleDetail><![CDATA[<P
> class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"></P>]]></ArticleDetail>'))
> FROM DUAL;
```

This is data

```
<ArticleDetail><![CDATA[<P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"></P>]]></ArticleDetail>
```

The xslt is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/x-json"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!--contant-->
  <xsl:variable name="d">0123456789</xsl:variable>

  <!-- ignore document text -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::node() or following-sibling::node()]"/>

  <!-- string -->
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Main template for escaping strings; used by above template and for object-properties
       Responsibilities: placed quotes around string, and chain up to next filter, escape-bs-string -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the backslash (\) before everything else. -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-bs-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,''\'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,''\''),''\\'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-bs-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,''\'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Escape the double quote ("). -->
  <xsl:template name="escape-quot-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''&quot;'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="escape-quot-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,'';'')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace tab, line feed and/or carriage return by its matching escape code. Can''t escape backslash
       or double quote here, because they don''t replace characters (; becomes \t), but they prefix
       characters (\ becomes \\). Besides, backslash should be seperate anyway, because it should be
       processed first. This function can''t do that. -->
  <xsl:template name="encode-string">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- tab -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\t'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- line feed -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\n'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- carriage return -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($s,'';'')">
        <xsl:call-template name="encode-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="s" select="concat(substring-before($s,'';''),''\r'',substring-after($s,'';''))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$s"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- number (no support for javascript mantise) -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(string(number())=''NaN'')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- boolean, case-insensitive -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,''TRUE'',''true'')=''true'']">true</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()[translate(.,''FALSE'',''false'')=''false'']">false</xsl:template>

  <!-- item:null -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(child::node())=0]">
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="local-name()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>:null</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if> <!-- MBR 30.01.2010: added this line as it appeared to be missing from stylesheet -->
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- object -->
  <xsl:template match="*" name="base">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">{</xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="name()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">}</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- array -->
  <xsl:template match="*[count(../*[name(../*)=name(.)])=count(../*) and count(../*)&gt;1]">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*)">[</xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(child::node())">
        <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">]</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- convert root element to an anonymous container -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what do you want to do with the contents of the CDATA section? It is not XML, looks like HTML.

Comment: Yes it is html inside the CDATA . is want it to come as it is and place the CDATA content inside some tag .So taht i can access it after convert by xslt.